# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop for switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement, key

Please tell me how to add a unique "key" prop for each child in a list.
It is a functional component in react:

```
<List component="nav">
  {bundlesData.map((bundleItem) => {
    switch (bundleItem) {
      case 'page':
        return pagesNavLink

      case 'menu':
        return (
          <MenuNavLink
            handleClick={handleClick}
            isOpened={isNavLinkOpened}
          />
        )

      default:
        return bundleItem
    }
  })}
</List>
```

Comment: Welcome. Your first question has a really good quality! Keep on asking like this! BTW, I think @lpizzinidev has answered this question clearly. Maybe consider accepting it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `index` to identify each `bundleItem`:

```
<List component='nav'>
  {bundlesData.map((bundleItem, index) => {
    switch (bundleItem) {
      case 'page':
        return <div key={index}>{pagesNavLink}</div>;

      case 'menu':
        return (
          <MenuNavLink
            key={index}
            handleClick={handleClick}
            isOpened={isNavLinkOpened}
          />
        );

      default:
        return <div key={index}>{bundleItem}</div>;
    }
  })}
</List>;
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do with a map function is it can take a second parameter which keeps track of the index. You can then use that index parameter on the list items as a key prop.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map